# How to show event at frontend

Tags: ethereum, web3js, truffle

I could successfully emitted event, but I don't know how to show those event.

My event is this

```
  event Sell (
    address indexed _buyer, 
    uint256 indexed _value
  );
```

I could get all event in console.

```
const event = await tokenSale.events.Sell({}, {
  fromBlock: 0,
  toBlock: 'latest',
})
event.on("data", (data) => console.log("data", data))
```

I want to show `_value` in frontend.

Could you give me any advise, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to render values in the front end. It depends on what language/library you are using. If you are using React, a nice tool for passing contract data to the front end is [Drizzle](https://truffleframework.com/docs/drizzle/quickstart)